# ASP print xml formatted string

Tags: asp.net, xml, xmp

I have:

```
tXML = "<type p_type=\"All\"/>";
```

if I do

```
Response.Write(tXML);
```

I get a blank space.

Is there anyway to output this string so I know it is being created?

Comment: You know that the string "is being created" when the server does not throw a syntax error message at you when you run the page… So I'm not sure what this means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Response.Write(Server.HtmlEncode(tXML));
```

Or "view source" in the browser...